# how data can be read from a text file and stored as as a structure?

Tags: c, file

Let's call this file f1.txt and it has given attributes.

- Student code
- name
- ID

and resident structure from another file let's call f2.txt will be read with the following attributes

- ID
- City

and residence will be asked from keyboard.

I tried to but gett stucked at some point

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student
{
    int student_code;
    char name[20];
    char ID[20];
};

int main()
{
    FILE *input_file;
    struct student input;

    input_file = fopen("f1.txt", "r");
    if(input_file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fread(&input, sizeof(struct student), 1, input_file))
        printf("student code = %d name = %s ID = %s", input.student_code, 
input.name, input.ID);
    fclose(input_file);

return 0;

}
```

I'm new at C programming

for example f1.txt file will be in the following format

```
f1.txt
123456 yourname 987654
564566 test 454545
```

Comment: You cannot `fread` text data directly info a _binary_ structure, you need to read the fields and convert them as appropriate.  You have not provided an example of the text file content, as such it is not possible to advise, but `fscanf()` is probably worth considering.  Moreover your struct does not match the data fields you mentioned and you say you "got stuck" but you have hardly started to the point that it is not clear what you need to do.

Comment: @Clifford I edited the question and showed the f1.txt file.

Comment: Does the f1.txt file really start with the line `f1.txt` as shown?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `fscanf` to read the lines because you know the format
2. Store the values into temporary variables
3. Copy them into a proper data structure: if you don't know the number of students use a dynamic array or a list.

EDIT:
Arrays allow random access, on the other hand lists only allow sequential access.
Here's my attempt using lists:

```
typedef struct student
{
    int student_code;
    char name[20];
    char ID[20];
    struct student* next;
}student_t;

typedef struct list_s
{
    int size;
    student_t* head;
    student_t* tail;
} list_t;

void list_push_back(list_t* l, int code, char n[20], char id[20])
{
    student_t* tmp = (student_t*)calloc(1,sizeof(*tmp));
    tmp->student_code = code;
    strncpy(tmp->name, n, 20);
    strncpy(tmp->ID, id, 20);

    if (l->head == NULL)
    {
        l->head = tmp;
        l->tail = tmp;
        l->size++;
        return;
    }

    l->tail->next = tmp;
    l->size++;
}

void list_print(list_t* l)
{
    student_t* it = l->head;

    while (it)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d %s %s\n", it->student_code, it->name, it->ID);
        it = it->next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *input_file;
    struct student input;

    input_file = fopen("f1.txt", "r");
    if (input_file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    list_t* list = (list_t*)calloc(1,sizeof(*list));

    char tmp_name[20];
    char tmp_id[20];
    int tmp_code = 0;

    while (fscanf(input_file, "%d %s %s", &tmp_code, tmp_name, tmp_id) != EOF)
    {
        list_push_back(list, tmp_code, tmp_name, tmp_id);
    }

    fclose(input_file);

    list_print(list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given the level Birkan is at, this is probably too complex a solution than he needs (or that his tutor will believe s his own work!).  This is more than just an answer to the question.

Comment: I know I've gone a bit too far, but he can start from my implementation to understand the details and eventually the whole picture.

Comment: I fear it may be a bit overwhelming and daunting - we don't want to scare anyone off.  A simple array implementation may have sufficed at this stage.  No need to learn everything at once.  No matter; so long as Birkan reads the comments, he should be reassured that this is an _extended_ answer.

Comment: Absolutely I didn't want to scare him off at all, I was trying to help, but you are right this is an **extended answer**. @Birkan: try simpler things first, like arrays, as in Clifford's answer.

Answer (score 0):

To read a single record into the structure `input`:

```
fscanf( input_file, "%d %s %s", &input.student_code, input.name, input.ID )
```

to read a integer and two strings into the relevant members.

`fscanf()` returns the number of formatted fields successfully assigned, so to display all records in the file in the manner your code attempts:

```
while( fscanf( input_file, "%d %s %s", &input.student_code, 
                                       input.name, 
                                       input.ID ) == 3 )
{
    printf( "student code = %d, name = %s, ID = %s\n", input.student_code,
                                                       input.name, 
                                                       input.ID ) ;
}
```